# How does Spyder run asyncio event loop in the background in same thread (or does it?)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, spyder

I've been studying the asyncio module/functionality for a couple of days now because I want to use it for the IO-bound parts of my application, and I think that I have a reasonable understanding of how it works by now, or at least I think I have understood the following;

1. Only one asyncio event loop can run in any one thread at any one time.
2. Once everything is set up and ready to go loop.run_forever() or loop.run_until_complete() is called to run the loop, and this call blocks the thread for good or until the loop has completed, ie. no sync code can (or should) run in parallel with the event-loop in the same thread.
3. If you need to run blocking/non-deterministic sync code from inside the event loop then you should run it inside an "Executor" which (if my understanding is correct) sort of embeds a thread or process pool inside the event loop and runs the code there (in its own new thread or process?)
4. The developers of python never intended for async code and sync code to be part of the same application, because I can find absolutely NO references explaining how best to implement inter thread/ inter sync/async code communication.
5. Asyncio was not written for humans.

With the above considerations in mind I have been thinking hard about how to run my async code in the background while doing other (sync) work in the foreground, I have also searched a lot on google, and have found many people with the same kind of problem but not many people who had a good solutions, and not any solutions that I was happy with.

**So now my question is; How does Spyder IDE do it???**

I'm using Spyder IDE and have discovered that Spyder runs its own asyncio event loop, and not only that, you can define and run async functions directly inside the interactive python console by just doing:

```
In [1]: async def my_printer():
   ...:     print('hello world')
   ...:
In [2]: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(my_printer(), asyncio.get_event_loop())
hello world
```

So I thought to my self "I wonder what thread the code I type in the Spyder terminal is actually executed in", so I tried:

```
In [3]: import threading
In [4]: threading.current_thread()
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 9756)>
```

..And then my confusion just grew even bigger when I then tried;

```
In [5]: async def get_thread():
   ...:     return threading.current_thread()
   ...:
In [6]: res = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(get_thread(), asyncio.get_event_loop())
In [7]: res.result()
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 9756)>
```

What the heck is going on here?

I don't understand how Spyder can run an asyncio event loop in the main thread, while still allowing me to run synchronous code in the same thread. Is my understanding not correct/ am I missing something about how asyncio works? or does Spyder employ some evil hack behind the scenes which makes it work?

I am mainly interested in this because I hope it can help me understand how sync and async code can work together, and because it might further my understanding of asyncio.

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/323). Spyder uses `ipykernel` to run code, so we're not really in charge of this.

Comment: Thank you for that, but does that basically mean that I can do things in a script that I run in Spyder that wont work if I run the script in a vanilla python, and it is not even a behaviour that I would be able to mimic when the script detects that it is not running in spyder? ie. it must be implemented in the kernel?? I understand that this is a feature of Spyder but I still don't really understand how it is implemented or whether there is a way for me to create a similar behaviour in a vanilla python script?

Comment: You have to remember that our IPython consoles are special because they are very geared towards interactive work. If you want the behavior you'll get from vanilla Python while working with Spyder, please go to the menu entry `Run > Configuration per file` and select the option `Execute in an external system terminal`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I appreciate your comments a lot, but I don't think you understand what I'm asking about. I understand that this is caused by the ipykernel, and I'm not looking to disable it, quite the opposite actually, I'm looking to understand how it works so that I can implement it my self in a script that runs in a vanilla python.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then you should ask about that in an issue in the `ipykernel` repo (although I doubt you can implement it outside of the Jupyter architecture).