# Spyder only: asyncio - cannot close a running event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, spyder

I am using Spyder portable version, with Python 3.7.9 64-bit | Qt 5.12.10 | PyQt5 5.12.3 | Windows 10

When trying to run next code:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def myWork():
    print("Starting Work")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Finishing Work")

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(myWork())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

directly in Command prompt, everything works OK, but when trying to run the same file from the Spyder, following error occurs:

```
runfile('C:/Users/6655/Documents/Crypto/async.py', wdir='C:/Users/6655/Documents/Crypto')
Starting Work
Finishing Work
ss
C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\IPython\core\ultratb.py:1366: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'myWork' was never awaited
  self.tb = tb
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\6655\Documents\Crypto\async.py", line 12, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(myWork())

  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\base_events.py", line 563, in run_until_complete

  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\base_events.py", line 526, in _check_runnung

RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

Does anybody have any idea, why only when using Spyder IDE this occurs, but not when running through CMD? I've also restarted Spyder and run this afresh, with no success

Comment: deleting 'async' in definition of myWork function makes the function execute, but after it is finished, it still produces error

Comment: i suspect it might be because spyder is in python and you are interacting with its loop. try using `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I tried with     loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()       but it still didn't work.

Comment: which errors did you get this time? could you update the question with the new stack trace?

Comment: sure, sorry... There are less errors now:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\6655\Documents\Crypto\playground.py", line 23, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(myWork())

  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\base_events.py", line 563, in run_until_complete

  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\base_events.py", line 526, in _check_runnung

RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Comment: you're running the code in an interactive console which makes this a little more compliacted as the console has its own loop. if you dont need the interactivity follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209456/how-does-spyder-run-asyncio-event-loop-in-the-background-in-same-thread-or-does#comment108300090_61209456) instructions. also read that question as it talks about the weirdness you are experiencing.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for your help, I'll read the link you provided

Comment: I don't know Spyder, but if its running an event loop and importing your code, you could probably just do `asyncio.create_task(myWork())` instead of `run_until_complete`. Sidenote: You do not ever want to use `time.sleep` in async code.

Comment: thanks, this actually works without any error. But there can't be finnally: loop.close() in the end..

Comment: If Spyder spins up the event loop you don't have to worry about that.